# XML Validation Failed

Tags: xml, netbeans-6.9, doctrine-orm

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
    xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                    http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="Entities\Aplikasi" table="aplikasi">
        <field name="nama" type="string" column="nama" length="20" precision="0" scale="0" unique="1"/>
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

I'm getting this result when trying to validate it through Netbeans

```
XML validation started.
Checking file:/home/meh/doctrine2/Entities/Mappings/Entities.Apliksi.dcm.xml...
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'doctrine-mapping'. [5] 
XML validation finished.
```

I also failed to validate the XML at http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/

How do I make sure it is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make a few changes to validate the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="EntitiesAplikasi" table="aplikasi">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>

        <field name="nama" type="string" column="nama" length="20" unique="1"/>
   </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

I had to add the prefix `xmlns` before `xsi` and the prefix `xsi` before `schemaLocation` and then I moved id above field and removed the precision and scale attributes.

If you navigate to [the schema](http://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd) in a web browser and choose view source or just download it you can read the schema to determine what the valid XML should look like.

Comment: Yeah, I just did that too, but the problem is, this XML was generated automatically from Doctrine 2 command line. So, does this means Doctrine 2 didn't generate a valid XML file?

Answer (score 1):

The same problem occurs while using Netbeans to validate any XML Schema (a XSD file, like any-xml-schema-name.xsd).

---

Before using your solution, my code was:

```
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

but it always fails to validate, with error message: **"Cannot find the declaration of element 'xs:schema'"**

---

Now, using your solution, I just changed the same code from above to:

```
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd"
```

and it is working.

---

Thanks!
Marcio Wesley Borges
http://marciowb.info